# QTreeWidget drag and drop

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

I have two `QTreeWidgets` in my form.
I need to make a drag and drop action from the first to the second `QTreeWidget`, but, I have one problem:

only one `QTreeWidgetItem` is copied, **without hierarchy**, without child items.

For the first `QTreeWidgets` I set dragDropMode -> `dragOnly`,
for the second I set dragDropMode -> `dropOnly` and defaultDropAction -> `copyAction`

How can I fix this?